# bs4 custom select doesn't work correctly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Here's bs4 example: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#select-menu

I'm using it on my site:

```
<select class="custom-select">
  <option value="1">Telegram</option>
  <option value="2">WhatsApp</option>
</select>
```

And result is looking this:

[image]

As you can see, there's double arrows, one from Chrome, another as background, why does this happen? Also i can't set paddings on this select list (not options, but select list itself)

**UPDATE**

There's something with my BS4, if i use it from CDN, then it works. I'm using it this way:

```
// Import full bs4
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Structure is:

[image]

i'm using it incorrectly?

Comment: Do you have other CSS that's impacting it? Hard to say if we can't reproduce.

Comment: I just wiped all css, and still this select is screwed. I included BS4 itself + bootstrap.min.js with. Maybe i am missing something?

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem: https://jsfiddle.net/5y8hpoyd/. You might want to create a code snippet in your answer where you can reproduce the problem with minimal code: see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, concrete and verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was in autoprefixer, i didn't use it. In my case i've used gulp, here's contents of gulpfile.js:

```
gulp.task('sass', function(){
    return gulp.src([
        'scss/app.scss'
    ])
        .pipe(sass()) // Converts Sass to CSS with gulp-sass
        .pipe(CleanCSS())
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
});
```

won't work without it.

Answer (score 1):

**I hope You Are not Try correctly, 
You Can Try this Code**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<select class="custom-select custom-select-lg mb-3 mt-5">
  <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Is popper.js required?

Comment: But My code steel worked. I hope you are something wrong or something missing.

Comment: Could you take a look at my updated question? Issue is in scss imports i think.

Comment: actually, I don't know Why don't work this code, I hope it's your another problem...